# What is the maximum number of key value pairs in a single hstore value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, hstore

I've got a postgres table (`mapfeatures_20120813`) with 2 columns (tags and pky) with around 1000 rows. Each row consists of a `hstore` and a primary key:

```
   tags (hstore)          pky
"aerialway"=>"cable_car";  1
"aerialway"=>"chair_lift"; 2
"aerialway"=>"drag_lift";  3
"aerialway"=>"gondola";    4
"aerialway"=>"goods";      5
"aerialway"=>"mixed_lift"; 6
"aerialway"=>"pylon";      7
"aerialway"=>"station";    8
"aeroway"=>"aerodrome";    9
"aeroway"=>"apron";        10
...
```

For some analysis I need to push all these single hstore key-value-pairs into one single hstore -row and I'm not sure how to solve this.
Therefore I first convert all the rows into a single-row text-field:

```
CREATE TABLE mf_text AS
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(tags), ',')
FROM mapfeatures_20120813;
```

In a second step I create a `hstore` out of this text-field:

```
SELECT hstore(array_to_string)
FROM mf_text
```

But the problem is that only 97 of the more than 1000 key-value-pairs are written into the new hstore-field. Also I can't see any pattern in my result, it's totally mixed up:

```
"atv"=>"no", "hgv"=>"forestry", "lit"=>"no", "psv"=>"private"
, "area"=>"yes", "boat"=>"permissive"
```

Is there some sort of limitation to an `hstore`-field on how many key-value-pairs fit into a single `hstore`? [The documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html) doesn't say anything.

Comment: Your title asks something different than the body of your question, I clarified as I understand your question. And *as always* add PostgreSQL version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregating a single hstore value should be as simple as:

```
SELECT string_agg(tags::text,',')::hstore
FROM   mapfeatures_20120813;
```

As to your question in the title: there is practically no limit to the number of elements.

For your remark:

> Also I can't see any pattern in my result, it's totally mixed up:

[The manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/hstore.html#AEN133841) has this to say:

> The order of the pairs is not significant (and may not be reproduced
>   on output).

Comment: Thanks for responding. Your answer solves my problem! Nevertheless out of curiosity: Is there a limitation of key-value-pairs to an hstore?

Comment: @C.B. Individual `varlena` fields are limited to 1GB (http://www.postgresql.org/about/) so I'd say that'll be your limit. The practical limit in performance terms is likely to come well before that. Test and see; I'll be interested in the results.

Comment: Interesting debate. Is there news on the matter ? I experienced max stack depth limitations far far below that varlena limited mentioned. Is there a better way to populate hstores with 50k-100k elements ?